# How to add li class when clicking another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs: #slider-next and #slider-prev. Also i have 4 li elements. On each click #slider-next i need to add .active class to each li.
First look:

```
   <ul class="items-list">
        <li class="active" id="l1">One</li>
        <li id="l2">Two</li>
        <li id="l3">Three</li>
        <li id="l4">Four</li>
    </ul>
```

After click #slider-next it should looks like:

```
<ul class="items-list">
    <li id="l1">One</li>
    <li class="active" id="l2">Two</li>
    <li id="l3">Three</li>
    <li id="l4">Four</li>
</ul>
```

It should repeating by clicking like it was at start
Here is my code but it adds class only for a second li:

```
function arrowNext() {
    if( $('#l1, #l2, #l3, #l4').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('.items-list li').removeClass('active');
        $('li:nth-child(1)').next().addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be perfect if someone write code for the #slider-prev button also :)

Comment: And your attempt? Or are you just hoping people on the internet will do everything for you without your thought and effort? (some might, but that's not the purpose of SO)

Comment: Here is my code :)

Comment: function arrowNext() {
      if( $('#l1, #l2, #l3, #l4').hasClass('active') ) {
       $('.items-list li').removeClass('active');
       $('li:nth-child(1)').next().addClass('active');
      }
     }

Comment: Edit your question with it :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it like this

```js
function arrowNav(prev) {
  // get the current index of the active item
  var index = $('.items-list li.active').index();

  // remove the active class from all items
  $('.items-list li').removeClass('active');

  // add or subtract one if next or previous
  var newIndex = prev ? index - 1 : index + 1;

  // rolling over the top or bottom
  if (newIndex < 0)
    newIndex = $('.items-list li').length - 1;
  else if (newIndex >= $('.items-list li').length)
    newIndex = 0;

  // setting the class of the new active item
  $('.items-list li').eq(newIndex).addClass('active');
}

$('#slider-prev').on('click', function() {
  arrowNav(true)
});
$('#slider-next').on('click', function() {
  arrowNav(false)
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items-list">
  <li class="active" id="l1">One</li>
  <li id="l2">Two</li>
  <li id="l3">Three</li>
  <li id="l4">Four</li>
</ul>
<button id="slider-prev">
  Prev
</button>
<button id="slider-next">
  Next
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If You need circular Next and Previous, you can try this:

```
var nextCircularIndex = function(currentIndex, totalIndex) {
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    return currentIndex % totalIndex;
}

var previousCircularIndex: function (currentIndex, totalIndex) {
    currentIndex = currentIndex - 1;
    return currentIndex < 0 ? totalIndex - 1 : currentIndex;
}
```

Then change `arrowNext` like

```
var currentSlider = 0;
var totalSlider = 4;

function arrowNext() {
   currentSlider = nextCircularIndex(currentSlider, totalSlider);
   $("ul.items-list li.active").removeClass('active');
   $("ul.items-list li:nth-child(" + currentSlider + ")").next().addClass('active');
}

function arrowPrevious() {
   currentSlider = previousCircularIndex(currentSlider, totalSlider);
   $("ul.items-list li.active").removeClass('active');
   $("ul.items-list li:nth-child(" + currentSlider + ")").next().addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good way you to follow

```
$(".next").on("click", function(){


if($(".active").next("div").html() === undefined) {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("div").first().addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".active").removeClass("active").next("div").addClass("active");
  }

})
$(".prev").on("click", function(){
    if($(".active").prev("div").html() === undefined) {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("div").last().addClass("active");
    } else {
    $(".active").removeClass("active").prev("div").addClass("active");
  }
})
```

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v58jzp9L/

here is a update with a loop :) https://jsfiddle.net/v58jzp9L/2/

Comment: but how to loop it? becouse it finishes on the last element

Comment: just check if it's the last one, if so go back to first

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```js
var list_items = $(".items-list li");
var li_active = 1;
var li_total = list_items.length;

$("#prev").click(function() {
  list_items.removeClass('active');
  if (li_active == 1) {
    li_active = li_total;
  } else {
    li_active--;
  }
  $('.items-list li:nth-child(' + li_active + ')').addClass('active');
});

$("#next").click(function() {
  list_items.removeClass('active');
  if (li_active == li_total) {
    li_active = 1;
  } else {
    li_active++;
  }
  $('.items-list li:nth-child(' + li_active + ')').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items-list">
  <li class="active" id="l1">One</li>
  <li id="l2">Two</li>
  <li id="l3">Three</li>
  <li id="l4">Four</li>
</ul>

<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

In general I would prefer to use `$(document).ready()` or something similar to ensure there is always one `class="active"` (since you're doing a slider seems sensible) as opposed to seeing if that condition exists.

`$('li:nth-child(1)')` selects the first `<li>` always, not the one that was previously active. What you probably want instead is

```
$('li.active')           // Selects the li with class active
  .removeClass('active') // returns the same li acted on
  .next()                // selects the next li
  .addClass('active');   // adds the class active
```

This method of "chaining" is part of what makes `jQuery` so convenient :)

If you want it to "wrap around" you could do something like

```
var $next = $('li.active')  // Selects the li with class active
  .removeClass('active')    // returns the same li acted on
  .next();                  // selects the next li
if ($next.length === 0) {
    $next = $('li:first');
}
$next.addClass('active');   // adds the class active
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
var item = $("ul").closest("li");
var item2 = item.closest(".active");
item2.toggleClass("active");

if (item2.next("li") != null) {
  item2.next("li").toggleClass("active");
} else {
  item.toggleClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have some conception of state that tracks which of the `li`s are `"active"`. This could be as simple as an array that looks like this:

```
const state = {
  list_items: [false, true, false, false]
};
```

Or, more succinctly, a single number, representing the index of the `li` that is `"active"`

```
const state = {
  active_list_item: 1
};
```

Then when you press next, you can increment `state.active_list_item` appropriately. Find a way to manage overflow. Does it wrap? If not, maybe use a `createClamp(..)` function. Otherwise, use a `createWrap(..)` function.

When the state is changed, you will want the appropriate DOM side effects to flow from the state change.

```
let list_items = document.getElementsByClassName('items-list')[0].children;
list_items = [].slice.apply(list_items);

list_items.forEach((list_item, i) => {
  if (i === state.active_list_item) {
    list_item.classList.add('active');
  }
  else {
    list_item.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

You should be able to figure out how to create the "previous" functionality now.